# Decorator to check input type in a class

Tags: python, python-decorators

By using decorator I can use to check variable type of function. Something like this:

```
def accepts(*types):
    def check_accepts(f):
        assert len(types) == f.__code__.co_argcount
        def new_f(*args, **kwds):
            for (a, t) in zip(args, types):
                assert isinstance(a, t), \
                       "arg %r does not match %s" % (a,t)
            return f(*args, **kwds)
        new_f.__name__ = f.__name__
        return new_f
    return check_accepts

@accepts(int, (int,float))
def func(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 * arg2

func(3, 2) # -> 6
func('3', 2) # -> AssertionError: arg '3' does not match <type 'int'>
```

It work well for normal simple. But i don't know how use it in class:

```
class Test()
   @accepts(pd.DataFrame)
   def print_dataframe(df):
        print(df)
```

I can't initital new class and use it.
Please show me how to use it

Answer (score 1):

As written, `print_dataframe` is an instance method, so you either need to take that into account:

```
NO_CHECK = object()

def accepts(*types):
    def check_accepts(f):
        assert len(types) == f.__code__.co_argcount
        def new_f(*args, **kwds):
            for (a, t) in zip(args, types):
                if t is NO_CHECK:
                    continue
                assert isinstance(a, t), \
                       "arg %r does not match %s" % (a,t)
            return f(*args, **kwds)
        new_f.__name__ = f.__name__
        return new_f
    return check_accepts

# Using NO_CHECK because it's easier to skip checking the self argument
# than it is to handle a check for that as-yet-undefined class Test
class Test():
   @accepts(NO_CHECK, pd.DataFrame)
   def print_dataframe(self, df):
        print(df)
```

or redefine `print_dataframe` to be a static method:

```
   class Test():
       @staticmethod
       @accepts(pd.DataFrame)
       def print_dataframe(df):
            print(df)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the parentheses from `object`?

Comment: No, that's intentional. I want a sentinel (distinct from `None`, since `mypy` has established the convention of using `None` in place of `type(None)` for type-checking), and `object` the class is a valid (if unlikely to be used) type for type-checking.

Comment: I mean, `NO_CHECK = object`. That would make the if clause obsolete as any object would pass the type check test.

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep "don't check this at all" distinct from "accept a value of any type". I *want* the sentinel to be something that isn't a type, and a vanilla instance of `object` is the simplest way to do that.

Comment: It's not work with @staticmethod because staticmethod has no attibute __code__ Could you have any solution for it

Comment: I was wondering about that. Try swapping the order of the decorators, so that you turn `new_f` into a static method, rather than trying to type-check a static method (which, indeed, is not a function, but an instance of `staticmethod` that *wraps* a function).

Comment: Could you describe your idea more detail? I'm not really clear.

Comment: `@staticmethod@accepts(...)def print_dataframe...` instead of `@accepts(...)@staticmethoddef print_dataframe...`. (Updated the answer, as swapping can't be any more wrong that the original.)